# How can I strip HTML in a string using Perl?

Tags: html, regex, perl, strip

Is there anyway easier than this to strip HTML from a string using Perl?

```
$Error_Msg =~ s|<b>||ig;
$Error_Msg =~ s|</b>||ig;
$Error_Msg =~ s|<h1>||ig;
$Error_Msg =~ s|</h1>||ig;
$Error_Msg =~ s|<br>||ig;
```

I would appreicate both a slimmed down regular expression, e.g. something like this:

```
$Error_Msg =~ s|</?[b|h1|br]>||ig;
```

Is there an existing Perl function that strips any/all HTML from a string, even though I only need bolds, h1 headers and br stripped?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming the code is valid HTML (no stray < or > operators)

```
$htmlCode =~ s|<.+?>||g;
```

If you need to remove only bolds, h1's and br's

```
$htmlCode =~ s#</?(?:b|h1|br)\b.*?>##g
```

And you might want to consider the [HTML::Strip](http://search.cpan.org/~kilinrax/HTML-Strip-1.04/) module

Comment: I wouldn't say might, I would say should.

Attempting to sanitize HTML with regexes is absurd in this day and age.

Use one of the numerous HTML sanitizing modules from the CPAN, preferably something designed to prevent XSS vulnerabilities and not written by Daniel Muey.

Comment: Beware HTML::Strip does not correctly support UTF-8 encoded strings. See here for a workaround https://gist.github.com/910818

Answer (score 16):

From [perlfaq9: How do I remove HTML from a string?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How_do_I_remove_HTML)

---

The most correct way (albeit not the fastest) is to use HTML::Parser from CPAN. Another mostly correct way is to use HTML::FormatText which not only removes HTML but also attempts to do a little simple formatting of the resulting plain text.

Many folks attempt a simple-minded regular expression approach, like s/<.*?>//g, but that fails in many cases because the tags may continue over line breaks, they may contain quoted angle-brackets, or HTML comment may be present. Plus, folks forget to convert entities--like < for example.

Here's one "simple-minded" approach, that works for most files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0777
s/<(?:[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>//gs
```

If you want a more complete solution, see the 3-stage striphtml program in http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TO/TOMC/scripts/striphtml.gz .

Here are some tricky cases that you should think about when picking a solution:

```
<IMG SRC = "foo.gif" ALT = "A > B">

<IMG SRC = "foo.gif"
 ALT = "A > B">

<!-- <A comment> -->

<script>if (a<b && a>c)</script>

<# Just data #>

<![INCLUDE CDATA [ >>>>>>>>>>>> ]]>
```

If HTML comments include other tags, those solutions would also break on text like this:

```
<!-- This section commented out.
    <B>You can't see me!</B>
-->
```

Comment: To your script suggestion --  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TO/TOMC/scripts/striphtml.gz -- this deletes everything. How can I modify this code to only leave certain html tags? Other than that it works well.

Answer (score 16):

You should definitely have a look at the [HTML::Restrict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Restrict) which allows you to strip away or restrict the HTML tags allowed. A minimal example that strips away all HTML tags:

```
use HTML::Restrict;

my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new();
my $processed = $hr->process('<b>i am bold</b>'); # returns 'i am bold'
```

I would recommend to stay away from HTML::Strip because [it breaks utf8 encoding](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=42834).

Comment: It doesn't work with Perl 5.8.x. It's a super program, but it would be nice to know what its support structure is.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if there is a way to leave the tags (allowable tags) that don't have open and close tags. Example '<br/>' is hard to identify.