# Perl RegEx help for matching string

Tags: regex, perl

**my string is** :

`<p class="paraind">Leo Frobenius und Johan Huizinga sehen wiederum in der Analogie von Fest und Spiel &#x201E;das Zusammengeben von strenger Bestimmtheit und echter Freiheit&#x201C;.<a id="cein_fn29" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn29"><sup>29</sup></a> Die rituelle Regelhaftigkeit einerseits und die Absenz des gew&#x00F6;hnlichen Lebens andererseits unterst&#x00FC;tzen den antipodischen Gehalt dieser beiden Kulturph&#x00E4;nomene, wobei das zweite Element auf den kompensatorischen Charakter des Festlichen verweist: Indem der Alltag im Festgeschehen periodisch durchbrochen wird, wird er ertr&#x00E4;glich, kann sich die &#x201E;Stabilisierung eines Ichs&#x201C; formieren.<a id="cein_fn30" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn30"><sup>30</sup></a> &#x201E;Das tempor&#x00E4;re Herausgenommensein aus dem Zwang des Alltags&#x201C; scheint hier zugleich Voraussetzung und Indiz f&#x00FC;r das Festliche zu sein. In dieser U-Chronie, in dieser Nicht-Zeit, kommt es zur synchronen Pr&#x00E4;senz von sehnsuchtsbehaftetem Wunschdenken und &#x201E;gleichzeitigem Wissen um das grunds&#x00E4;tzlich Prek&#x00E4;re&#x201C;.<a id="cein_fn31" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn31"><sup>31</sup></a> Nur in den mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist  die &#x201E;vor&#x00FC;bergehende M&#x00F6;glichkeit des Entkommens aus dem Normalen aus den Routinen und Zw&#x00E4;ngen&#x201C; gegeben.<a id="cein_fn32" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn32"><sup>32</sup></a></p>`

**I want to find :**

> das grunds&#x00E4;tzlich Prek&#x00E4;re&#x201C;. Nur in den
>   mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen

**Note:** I am finding the above string from variable so i cant match it if any tag present inside.

Somebody please suggest any regular expression for this

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract text between said tags?

Comment: I want to extranct text AFTER said tags, Tejas

Comment: What's the output you're expecting here? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I want to find "das grunds&#x00E4;tzlich Prek&#x00E4;re&#x201C;. Nur in den mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen" in the above string but I AM FINDING THE STRING FROM VARIABLE and "<a>" tag also present inside the matching string on above, so I cant find this

Comment: question updated pls check

Comment: So you want to strip the big string from HTML tags in order to check if your variable string is inside it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I strip HTML in a string using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067414/how-can-i-strip-html-in-a-string-using-perl) or [strip HTML Tags with perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176842/strip-html-tags-with-perl)

Answer (score 2):

```
 use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $str = "Your HTML STRING";

# Now create a new tree to parse the HTML
my $tr = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($str);

# And now find all required tags ex li and create an array
my @lists = map { $_->content_list }  $tr->find_by_tag_name('li');

# And loop through the array printing values of tag.
foreach my $val (@lists) {
   print $val, "\n";
}
```

Do the same thing for all other tags.

It is always recommended that you parse HTML instead of using regex for extraction purpose. It is very difficult to write 100% accurate regex for the purpose.

Comment: question updated pls check

Answer (score 0):

if you want the text between the tags you have mentioned. you can do it like this:

```
<tagyouwant>([^<]+)
```

and you will get the text in match groups.

for eg , suppose you want : 29, 30, 31, 32 i.e. text inside `<sup>`

so you will write the regex as : `<sup>([^<]+)`

similarly for other tags.

Comment: question updated pls check

Answer (score 0):

I would use this to extract matches. It would be better to use some kind of HTML parser, but this works.

It is very uneffective, do not use it for production.

```
my $str = '<p class="paraind">Leo Frobenius und Johan Huizinga sehen wiederum in der Analogie von Fest und Spiel 
&#x201E;das Zusammengeben von strenger Bestimmtheit und echter Freiheit&#x201C;.
<a id="cein_fn29" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn29"><sup>29</sup></a>
 Die rituelle Regelhaftigkeit einerseits und die Absenz des gew&#x00F6;hnlichen Lebens andererseits unterst&#x00FC;tzen den antipodischen Gehalt dieser beiden Kulturph&#x00E4;nomene, wobei das zweite Element auf den kompensatorischen Charakter des Festlichen verweist: Indem der Alltag im Festgeschehen periodisch durchbrochen wird, wird er ertr&#x00E4;glich, kann sich die &#x201E;Stabilisierung eines Ichs&#x201C; formieren.<a id="cein_fn30" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn30"><sup>30</sup></a>
 &#x201E;Das tempor&#x00E4;re Herausgenommensein aus dem Zwang des Alltags&#x201C; scheint hier zugleich Voraussetzung und Indiz f&#x00FC;r das Festliche zu sein. In dieser U-Chronie, in dieser Nicht-Zeit, kommt es zur synchronen Pr&#x00E4;senz von sehnsuchtsbehaftetem Wunschdenken und &#x201E;gleichzeitigem Wissen um das grunds&#x00E4;tzlich Prek&#x00E4;re&#x201C;.<a id="cein_fn31" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn31"><sup>31</sup></a> Nur in den mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist die &#x201E;vor&#x00FC;bergehende M&#x00F6;glichkeit des Entkommens aus dem Normalen aus den Routinen und Zw&#x00E4;ngen&#x201C; gegeben.
 <a id="cein_fn32" href="einleitung.html#ein_fn32"><sup>32</sup></a></p>
 <span test>test text</span>
 ';
foreach my $tag (qw|i b span sup sub a|){
    my $s = $str;
    while ($s =~ s!<($tag)[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>!!is){
      print "Match: $1\ttext: $2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: question updated pls check